# Mongoid belongs_to specify foreign_key

Tags: foreign-keys, mongoid

I'd like to set up a relationship between two Mongoid models with has_many and belongs_to and specify a foreign key, like so:

```
class Author
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :serial_num, :type => Integer
  field :author_name, :type => String

  has_many :books
end

class Book
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :serial_num, :type => Integer
  field :book_name, :type => String

  belongs_to :author, foreign_key: 'serial_num'
end
```

This doesn't work, however. My IRB output:

```
irb :001> b = Book.first
=> #<Book _id: 1, serial_num: "12345", book_name: 'something', author_id: nil>
irb :002> b.author
=> nil
```

Is it possible to specify 'serial_num' as a foreign key for this relationship, or am I stuck with author_id?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set both `foreign_key` and `primary_key` given your field definitions. The code you gave does respect  `primary_key` but on author this value is looked up in `_id`, not `serial_num`. See [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-relations/#custom-primary-foreign-keys) for further details and examples.

```
  belongs_to :author, foreign_key: 'serial_num', primary_key: 'serial_num'
```

Comment: Just to update the docs link: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-relations/#custom-primary-foreign-keys

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old post, but I'm guessing it has to do with the field type the foreign key is stored as.  If it's not a BSON ObjectId, then it may not return anything.